# How prolog deals with this step-by-step?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to understand prolog but I am stuck with one example, can you explain to me how is prolog going through this call:

`eli(2,[2,2,1],L)`.

using those facts:

```
eli(X,[],[]).
eli(X,[Y],[Y]).
eli(X,[X,X|L],L1) :- eli(X,L,L1).
eli(X,[Y|L],[Y|L1]) :- eli(X,L,L1).
```

The results are:

```
L = [1]
L = [1]
L = [2, 2, 1]
L = [2, 2, 1]
```

and I'm not really sure why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you wondering how you got the repeated results specifically, or any of those results in general? Your second rule is redundant with your 4th rule (the 4th rule in conjunction with the 1st rule handle that case already). And your 3rd and 4th rules have overlap as well, so you will get some repeat solutions.

Comment: Both, I tried to write it down on paper but I was getting different results + not repeated. Can you explain that to me with wider view?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your predicate is mean to delete two consecutive appearance of any element.

First clause, if the target list is empty, return the empty list. In this case the X variable in the fact is not necessary. Replace X by te anonymous variable.

```
eli(_,[],[]).
```

Second clause is similar to the first, but it matches the target list if it contains only one element. Variable X is also not necessary.

```
eli(_,[Y],[Y]).
```

Third clause, if the target list contains two or more elements, and in the Head of the list both elements are equal to X, don't copy this two elements to the Result list, and make a recursive call to the `eli/3` predicate in the body of the rule, to continue the search.

```
eli(X,[X,X|L],L1) :- eli(X,L,L1), !.
```

In this case we add the `cut` predicate, to avoid backtracking after this rule succeeded. Otherwise you may get undesired results, like `L = [2, 2, 1]` in your test.
And the last clause, copy the element in the Head of the Target list to the Result list, and continue the recursive call, this will stop when the Target list is empty or contains only one element (your first two clauses).

```
eli(X,[Y|L],[Y|L1]) :- eli(X,L,L1).
```

Now this is your predicate `eli/3`:

```
eli(_,[],[]).
eli(_,[Y],[Y]).
eli(X,[X,X|L],L1) :- eli(X,L,L1), !.
eli(X,[Y|L],[Y|L1]) :- eli(X,L,L1).
```

Test:

```
?- eli(2,[2,2,1],L).
L = [1]

?- eli(2,[1,2,2,3],L).
L = [1, 3]
```

Comment: I took this example from my last exam. It's about to spot those "mistakes" by drawing it with tree representation. 

The point is, that the first result is = 1. Im not sure where does it receive that value.